# Adding Unique constraints for two fields and don't allow duplicate entries if both are repeating

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to stop duplicate entries only if two columns are repeating the same value.

I am using MySQL.

**for example**
I have one table "voting" and fields are

```
id
vote
user_id
message_id
```

In this user can enter up or down vote for a message. 
I don't want the user to add multiple vote for the same message 
i.e if user_id 1 votes up to message_id 1 
then if the same user votes up again for same message , i don't want to allow this repeating process .

I mean is there any way to set unique constraints for fields user_id and message_id and don't allow to insert a row if **user_id and message_id is repeating**.

I know we can stop it using logical code using php.

I am expecting answers is there any way to do this using mysql only.?

Comment: Of course there is, it's called compound unique index. Alter the table and add `UNIQUE(user_id, message_id)`. That way you allow 1 user to vote once for 1 message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
 ADD CONSTRAINT uc_user_message UNIQUE (user_id ,message_id )
```